# Ignore timestamp when installing a package with dpkg?

Tags: dpkg

I'm working with two virtualized servers which keep time extremely poorly for some reason, so that one is always a little bit ahead of the other (up to 2 seconds). The problem I'm having is that I build packages on the one "in the future", and then the other machine refuses to install them. The build-upload-install is one step, so I could potentially just add a delay, but I'd prefer not to.

Is there a way to tell dpkg to just ignore the timestamp?

The error message looks like this:

```
 [exec] Command: sudo /usr/bin/dpkg -i /home/deploy/Media/Media_2011-09-06_100724.deb
 [exec] Error: tar: ./control: time stamp 2011-09-06 10:07:47 is 2.68160212 s in the future
 [exec] tar: ./control-template: time stamp 2011-09-06 10:07:46 is 1.681412205 s in the future
 [exec] tar: ./postinst: time stamp 2011-09-06 10:07:46 is 1.681347869 s in the future
 [exec] tar: .: time stamp 2011-09-06 10:07:47 is 2.681313485 s in the future
```

(it's part of an ant script)

Comment: Probably a `--force-all` could help, nevertheless it is overkill. I would see the exact error message.

Comment: I think fixing your time problem shouldn't be very complicated and is the best way to solve your problem instead of looking for some workaround to ignore it.

Comment: What's the error you see? How are you installing the package?

Comment: @Iain Lane, I added the error message

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to install the `ntp` package to get time sync working correctly, but barring that, you could trick the other system's "dpkg" into thinking it is living in the future by installing the `faketime` package, and running it with "-f +10s":

```
$ date +%H:%M:%S; faketime -f +10s date +%H:%M:%S
22:38:52
22:39:02
```